# Set Multiple values in a Single cookie Java code

Tags: java, jetty, httpcookie

I want to set multiple values in a single cookie & tried different thing but nothing seems to work.

```
 Following is cookie i want:-

    Cookie:_ga=GA1.2.58901287.1482689103; 
           _mkto_trk=id:847-FEI-694&token:_abc.com-1476661358764-46786; 
           __nfmp=5dbb3560-289b-4887-ac75-f28862b22072;  
           IP_ABC=159; 
          -http-session-=29::http.session::3f703e6f4a0ebf8bbb5081fbc7845790
```

Following is my code in Java And i would need code in JAVA only

```
       List<HttpCookie> cookies = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie("-http-session-", cookieVal);
        cookies.add(cookie1);
        request.setCookies(cookies);
        request.setSubProtocols("ao-json");
```

How to add another value in same cookie.Above code is part of Jetty library. If something can be done in Jetty it would be really great.